# How to Display a List of Child Pages For a Parent Page in WordPress

Tags: php, functions, pages

I need to display child pages on my parent pages. i have a code that is working but i need to set some codes to only show specific pages like to only show visibility public not all the pages.

this is the code for the function.php to display the child pages on my parent page.

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() {

global $post;

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )

    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
else
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

if ( $childpages ) {

    $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';

} 

return $string;

}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```

shortcode

```
[wpb_childpages]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `post_status`.

**post_status** 
A comma-separated list of post status types that should be included. For example, 'publish,private'.

possible values are: (publish|inherit|pending|private|future|draft|trash)

or you can also play with:

**include** 
 Only include certain Pages in the list generated by wp_list_pages. This parameter takes a comma-separated list of Page IDs.

more about it here.. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: where do i put that on my code sir? i dont know about php

Comment: put inside `wp_list_pages`. sample: `wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&post_status=private,publish&include=133,441&title_li=&child_...`

Comment: please read the link given...

Comment: i added it on the echo not on the sort column because it display the pages if i add the post status.

also the publish is not working it also displays the private. i need to display the public pages only but there is no coded for visibility.

Comment: no worries i think i figure it out myself thanks for the help though